# Instantiating and associating Ahoy::Visit for RSpec System Testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, capybara, rspec-rails, ahoy

#### Env

- Rails 7.0.4
- Capybara 3.39.1
- Rspec 3.12.2
- Rspec Rails 6.0.2
- AhoyMatey 4.2.1

#### General Context

We have an app that uses `current_visit` as a stand-in user model when a user is not authenticated. We allow a user to "trial" the application, then request they register an account to continue after completing our wizard once. We then associate resources from `current_visit` with `current_user` using the Devise `after_sign_in` method. We also use Pundit, and have a `UserContext` object, but I don't think that's relevant for this particular question.

#### Problem Context

I am trying to write system tests and want to be able to instantiate a visit to a certain state. For example, we have two resources a user could optionally have and I'd like to be able to instantiate a visit into these states:

- Visitor is new user, has no associations
- Visitor has an associated resource A, but no associated resource B
- Visitor has both associated resources A and B

Visitor could have associated resource B but not A, but this is not common, nor possible via the UI (which is the focus of this system test).

#### Problem

I have added an edit below about an additional approach using mocks.

I am able to instantiate a visitor in my system tests, and they are successfully created in the system test. Using the debugger, I can confirm that the visitor responds to the right methods as I expect, as I can call `expect(visitor.reload.resource_a.size).to eq(1)` and pass the spec

However, it seems that this visitor is not associated with the `current_visit` on the backend in the system test, as even though the instance of `visitor` has the traits I want, the frontend does not display this instantiated visit.

I have tried to initiate a tracker in my system test:

```rb
let(:visitor) { create(:ahoyvisit, :with_resources) }
let(:tracker) { Ahoy::Tracker.new(visitor_token: visitor.token) }
```

But this doesn't seem to work to associate the created visitor to `current_visit` in the controller. I am generally unsure how I should properly bridge this gap in my system testing.

[edit]

#### Mocks

It was suggested to me to try using a mock, but that also didn't seem to work:
`allow_any_instance_of(Ahoy::Tracker).to receive(:visit).and_return(visitor)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a mock was the way to go. I simply had to make sure I was mocking the right method and response *before* visiting my route like so:

```rb
it "shows the right thing" do
  allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationController).to receive(:current_visit).and_return(visitor)

  visit resource_path
  expect(page).to have_text(visitor.resource.first.title)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Mocking is generally the preferred solution, but if you want to look at a hack (which is generally frowned upon), check out

https://github.com/railsware/rack_session_access

I would only do this in a limited fashion and mocking is probably the cleaner, more appropriate choice. But the gem does work, although most people don't know about it or use it, I have had success getting it to work.